# Big Data integration testing best practice

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm, bigdata

I am looking around for some resources on what best practices are for a AWS based data ingestion pipeline that is using Kafka, storm, spark (streaming and batch) which read from and write to Hbase using various micro services to expose the data layer. For my local env I am thinking of creating either docker or vagrant images that will allow me to interact with the env. My issue becomes as to how to standup something for a functional end to end environment which is closer to prod, the drop dead way would be to have an always on environment but that gets expensive. Along the same lines in terms of a perf environment it seems like I might have to punt and have service accounts that can have the 'run of the world' but other accounts that will be limited via compute resources so they don't overwhelm the cluster.

I am curious how others have handled the same problem and if I am thinking of this backwards.

Answer (score 0):

AWS also provides a Docker Service via EC2 Containers. If your local deployment using Docker images is successful, you can check out AWS EC2 Container Service (https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

Also, check out storm-docker (https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-docker), provides easy to use docker-files for deploying storm clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Try hadoop mini clusters. It has support for most of the tools you are using.

[Mini Cluster](https://github.com/sakserv/hadoop-mini-clusters)